# How to format reference line in lightweight charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

How to format reference line in lightweight charts?

Following is lightweight chart.
As you can se the horizontal line market (`US$449,308,044`) is taking so much space.

Is there a way to format this text?

[image]

```
      var chart = createChart(ref.current, {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        layout: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          textColor: textColor,
        },
        rightPriceScale: {
          scaleMargins: {
            top: topScale,
            bottom: 0,
          },
          borderVisible: false,
        },
        timeScale: {
          borderVisible: false,
        },
        grid: {
          horzLines: {
            color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
            visible: false,
          },
          vertLines: {
            color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
            visible: false,
          },
        },
        crosshair: {
          horzLine: {
            visible: false,
            labelVisible: false,
          },
          vertLine: {
            visible: true,
            style: 0,
            width: 2,
            color: 'rgba(32, 38, 46, 0.1)',
            labelVisible: false,
          },
        },
        localization: {
          priceFormatter: (val) => formattedNum(val, true),
        },
      });
```

Comment: Could you share codesandbox or jsfiddle code to do debug?

Comment: Mine is a bit complicated. But here is sample code. https://codesandbox.io/s/9inkb

I want the text in the reference line to be formatted (like k, m for million, b for billion ... like that!) Hope you got @Evren

Comment: The reference line I mean the horizontal like that shows the latest price (dotted line)

Comment: Any help?? Someone??

Comment: @mx_code can you please provide jsfiddle of your chart? In your code data and formattedNum is not defined at least. Also, how do you create your series? Looks like you provide some options there, but you didn't provide them in your code sample.

Comment: @mx_code as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/a40eov3t/1/ `localization.priceFormat` is applied to all values on price axis.

Comment: Yes. I can see that. But is there a way to separately format the horizontal reference line?

Answer (score -1):

```
function formattedNum(val) {
return val + 'sssssssss';
}    
var chart = createChart(ref.current, {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    layout: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      textColor: textColor,
    },
    rightPriceScale: {
      scaleMargins: {
        top: topScale,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      borderVisible: false,
    },
    timeScale: {
      borderVisible: false,
    },
    grid: {
      horzLines: {
        color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
        visible: false,
      },
      vertLines: {
        color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
        visible: false,
      },
    },
    crosshair: {
      horzLine: {
        visible: false,
        labelVisible: false,
      },
      vertLine: {
        visible: true,
        style: 0,
        width: 2,
        color: 'rgba(32, 38, 46, 0.1)',
        labelVisible: false,
      },
    },
    localization: {
     priceFormatter: (val) => "$"+val.toFixed(2) + "b",
    },
  });`
```

i added corrections to your priceFormatter

Comment: This is poorly formatted, irrelevant code, and doesn't actually contribute anything to the solution. Please post things like this in the comments, if even at all.

Comment: it's formatted correctly. the solution actually works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34345471)